# Convert to NaN if cell is in the top or bottom x%

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers, quantile

I'm looking to trim my dataframe by removing the top and bottom 5% or so of data from specific columns. There are erroneous outliers that are preventing me from using the data effectively.

The dataframe has a "name" column and a few other non-numeric columns, so I want to be able to select specific columns to trim the df from.

I think converting the cell to NaN if its value is the in the largest or smallest x% would be an effective way to do it, but I'm open to other ways if they work, too.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for column in df.columns:
    top = column.quantile(0.95)
    bottom = column.quantile(0.05)
    for cell in column:
        if (cell >= top)|(cell <= bottom):
            cell = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `between`. Also, you can pass an array to `quantile()`:

```
for column in [your_list_of_columns]:
    bottom, top = df[column].quantile([0.05,0.95])

    df[column] = df[column].where(df[column].between(bottom, top))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [np.argpartation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) method like below to select top and bottom 5% data from each column. This will be more efficient as it uses vectorization and also don't need to sort all rows

```py
bottom_ind = np.argpartition(df.values, trim_len, axis=0)[:trim_len]
top_ind = np.argpartition(df.values, -trim_len, axis=0)[-trim_len:]
trim_ind = np.r_[bottom_ind, top_ind]

## you can use loop here if you have more columns
df.iloc[trim_ind[0],0] = np.nan
df.iloc[trim_ind[1],1] = np.nan
df
```